# Kedro - how to pass nested parameters directly to node

Tags: machine-learning, yaml, pipeline, kedro

[`kedro`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kedro) recommends storing parameters in `conf/base/parameters.yml`. Let's assume it looks like this:

```
step_size: 1
model_params:
    learning_rate: 0.01
    test_data_ratio: 0.2
    num_train_steps: 10000
```

And now imagine I have some `data_engineering` pipeline whose `nodes.py` has a function that looks something like this:

```
def some_pipeline_step(num_train_steps):
    """
    Takes the parameter `num_train_steps` as argument.
    """
    pass
```

How would I go about and pass that nested parameters straight to this function in `data_engineering/pipeline.py`? I unsuccessfully tried:

```
from kedro.pipeline import Pipeline, node

from .nodes import split_data


def create_pipeline(**kwargs):
    return Pipeline(
        [
            node(
                some_pipeline_step,
                ["params:model_params.num_train_steps"],
                dict(
                    train_x="train_x",
                    train_y="train_y",
                ),
            )
        ]
    )
```

I know that I could just pass all parameters into the function by using `['parameters']` or just pass all `model_params` parameters with `['params:model_params']` but it seems unelegant and I feel like there must be a way. Would appreciate any input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm part of the Kedro team)

Thank you for your question. Current version of Kedro, unfortunately, does not support nested parameters. The interim solution would be to use top-level keys inside the node (as you already pointed out) or decorate your node function with some sort of a parameter filter, which is not elegant either.

Probably the most viable solution would be to customise your `ProjectContext` (in `src/<package_name>/run.py`) class by overwriting `_get_feed_dict` method as follows:

```py
class ProjectContext(KedroContext):
    # ...


    def _get_feed_dict(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        """Get parameters and return the feed dictionary."""
        params = self.params
        feed_dict = {"parameters": params}

        def _add_param_to_feed_dict(param_name, param_value):
            """This recursively adds parameter paths to the `feed_dict`,
            whenever `param_value` is a dictionary itself, so that users can
            specify specific nested parameters in their node inputs.

            Example:

                >>> param_name = "a"
                >>> param_value = {"b": 1}
                >>> _add_param_to_feed_dict(param_name, param_value)
                >>> assert feed_dict["params:a"] == {"b": 1}
                >>> assert feed_dict["params:a.b"] == 1
            """
            key = "params:{}".format(param_name)
            feed_dict[key] = param_value

            if isinstance(param_value, dict):
                for key, val in param_value.items():
                    _add_param_to_feed_dict("{}.{}".format(param_name, key), val)

        for param_name, param_value in params.items():
            _add_param_to_feed_dict(param_name, param_value)

        return feed_dict
```

Please also note that this issue has already been [addressed on develop](https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro/commit/529606273e201a736f10338ada73ac6206081730) and will become available in the next release. The fix uses the approach from the snippet above.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Dmitry, `kedro 0.16.0` [introduced](https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro/blob/main/RELEASE.md#0160) nested parameter values  inside the node inputs which can be accessed via `.` operator:

```
node(func, "params:a.b", None)
```

whereas `kedro 0.17.6` [enabled overriding nested parameters with `params` in CLI](https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro/blob/main/RELEASE.md#release-0176), e.g.

```
kedro run --params="model.model_tuning.booster:gbtree"
```